# I was trying to Change the row color in DataGridView based on the quantity of a cell value but first row doesn't change

Tags: vb.net, row, background-color

I used this code and its working fine but the problem is the first row doesn't change the color, only starting from 2nd row is changing, does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

```
 Private Sub dgvItems2_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvItems2.CellFormatting
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvItems2.Rows.Count - 1
        If dgvItems2.Rows(i).Cells("Status").Value = "Active" Then
            dgvItems2.Rows(i).Cells("Status").Style.ForeColor = Color.Red

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You dont need to loop thru all rows in a cell event and that might not be the best place to set the color

Comment: can you help me fix this problem sir? do you have any suggestion or sample code which i can use. Thank you

Comment: Read the answer on the duplicate - you have almost all the same problems